# how to align components in a row?

Tags: reactjs

```
code
          <div className="socials">
            <Social logo={github} title="GitHub" />
            <Social logo={linkedin} title="Linkedin" />
            <Social logo={whatsapp} title="Whatsapp" />
            <Social logo={facebook} title="Facebook" />
            <Social logo={discord} title="Discord" />
            <Social logo={twitter} title="Twitter" />
          </div>

____________________________________________________________________
scss

    .socials {
        display: flex;
      }
```

as it can be seen its in a column i want it in a row
these are the scoial media links with logo and title like small cards and the are showing as a vertical but i want them in horizontal order

Answer (score 1):

`flex-direction` is default to row, but you can modify it in your css/scss file.

```css
flex-direction: row;
```

Then you can just do

```css
align-items: center;
```

to center the items.

Comment: Thank you for the response but i have tried flex direction row but its not working

Answer (score 0):

To make the items display in a horizontal row, you can use the flex-direction property. Here's how you can adjust your SCSS code:

```
.socials {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* Set the flex direction to row */
}
```